# Putting several footnotes below the table

Tags: tables, footnotes

I'm having trouble putting notes below the table - I want to put several notes below the table but the footnote seems to stretch, making the table longer than necessary. Would there be a way to fix this?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering \caption{Summary Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Std. Dev.} & \textbf{N}\\
\hline
a & a & a & a \\
\hline
\label{table2}
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textsuperscript{*}\footnotesize{blah blah}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I just put notes into the caption. That way people won't miss seeing them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the `threeparttable` package, that's designed for that sort of things. In the following code, I added the `caption` package, to ensure a proper spacing between caption and table, `booktabs` and the `makecell` package, that allows for common formatting of column heads.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[! htbp]\centering \caption{Summary Statistics}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\toprule\midrule
\thead{Variable} & \thead{Mean}
 & \thead{Std. Dev.} & \thead{N}\\ \midrule
a & a & a\tnote{*} & a \\
\bottomrule\addlinespace[1ex]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[*] Blahblah
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should a `\tnote{*}` directive be inserted somewhere in the `tabular` environment?

Comment: Yes. As your code didn't contain anything of the sort I didnt put one. Another remark: there is a `threepartablex` package that works with long tables, that break across pages, and a slightly different syntax.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback! I actually tried threeparttable but the note below seems to align towards the center rather than as it should in an ordinary text. If the note is short, it is no problem, but my note is long and threeparttable doesn't seem to align the note well. Please see after inputing longer text after \item

Comment: I'll take a look at this and come back in a moment.

Comment: @user2298759: I have no such problem. You can try the `flushleft` option on loading the package.

Comment: @Bernard I had trouble because of \bottomrule\addlinespace[1exA] but just doing \bottomrule worked. Thanks!

Comment: @user229759: Sorry, I mistyped `\addlinespace[1ex]` (no `A`). Corrected my code.

Comment: As a note, in normal `booktabs` usage, `\toprule` should be by itself and the `\hline` should be replaced with `\midrule`.

Comment: Hello @Bernard, how can I insert the * below the "Std. Dev." row? In this case I'd like to write a*.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi: Use  `\tnote{*}` right after the third a. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Actually the name of the package that works with long tables is [`threeparttablex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex), with a double `t`. `:)`

Comment: @Leone: It is worth mentioning the syntax of `threeparttablex`  is somewhat different from the syntax of `threeparttable`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in command `\tabularnote`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,enumitem,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}lp{8cm}@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Activity} & \textbf{Activity Sequence}\\
\midrule
Getting on a Tram\tabularnote{Note that \textit{Getting On Sequence} will start from steady standing in the station.}& Standing, Walking, Turn Left or right, walk, climb up stairs, turn left or right, walk again till reach seat, turn left or right $90°$ or $180°$, seat down, sitting for long time.  \\
 Getting off a Tram\tabularnote{Note that \textit{Getting Off Sequence} will start from steady sitting state in the
   Tram.}& Sitting, stand up, turn left or right $90°$ or $180°$, walk till reach the door, turn left or right to
 reach stairs, climb down, walk out from the Tram.  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Getting on/off passengers' activity states}
\label{tab:GettingOnOffPassengersActivityStates}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This is without question better than the excepted answer, since automatically labelled and hyperreferenced footnotes are supported (as they always should be for any footnote package, else just use MS Word)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{10cm}
\begin{threeparttable}[t]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
 \hline
\textbf{Activity} & \textbf{Activity Sequence}\\\hline
 Getting on a Tram \tnote{1}& \multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}|}{Standing, Walking, Turn Left or right, walk, climb up stairs, turn left or right, walk again till reach seat, turn left or right 90$^{\circ}$ or 180$^{\circ}$, seat down, sitting for long time.}  \\\hline 
 Getting off a Tram\tnote{2}& \multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}|}{Sitting, stand up, turn left or right 90$^{\circ}$ or 180$^{\circ}$, walk till reach the door, turn left or right to reach stairs, climb down, walk out from the Tram.}  \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
     \item[1] Note that \textit{Getting On Sequence} will start from steady standing in the station.
     \item[2] Note that \textit{Getting Off Sequence} will start from steady sitting state in the Tram.
   \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}
    \caption{Getting on/off passengers' activity states}
    \label{tab:GettingOnOffPassengersActivityStates}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference to Bernard's answer? Btw. if you post code, it should be compilable see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{m{6cm}|}{...}` does not make much sense. You could write `m{6cm}|` in the parameter of the `tabular`.

Comment: [duplicate answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443416/123129)